# Create a generic procedure, which inserts data into any table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on a .NET application and want to make it as modular as possible. I've already created a basic SELECT procedure, which returns data by checking inputted parameters on SQL Server side.

I want to create a procedure that parses structured data as string and inserts its' contents to corresponding table in database.

For example, I have a table as

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable ( 
  id_exampleTable int    IDENTITY (1, 1)  NOT NULL,
  exampleColumn1  nvarchar(200)           NOT NULL,
  exampleColumn2  int                     NULL,
  exampleColumn3  int                     NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT pk_exampleTable PRIMARY KEY  ( id_exampleTable ) 
)
```

And my procedure starts as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertDataIntoCorrespondingTable
  @dataTable nvarchar(max), --name of Table in my DB
  @data nvarchar(max) --normalized string parameter as 'column1, column2, column3, etc.'
AS

BEGIN

  IF @dataTable = 'table'

    BEGIN
      /**Parse this string and execute insert command**/
    END

   ELSE IF /**Other statements**/
END
```

**TL;DR**

So basically, I'm looking for a solution that can help me achieve something like this

```
EXEC InsertDataIntoCorrespondingTableByID(
  @dataTable = 'ExampleTable', 
  @data = '''exampleColumn1'', 2, 3'
)
```

Which should be equal to just

```
INSERT INTO ExampleTable SELECT 'exampleColumn1', 2, 3
```

Sure, I can push data as INSERT statements (for each and every 14 tables inside DB...), generated inside an app, but I want to conquer T-SQL :)

Comment: Thats not mastering SQL, thats butchering it :) SQL is not designed for DRY coding and shouldn't be approached as such. Its designed for static statements and you should use it that way unless you have a very good reason not to. If you consider you have exceptional circumstances, then research dynamic SQL... but I suggest avoiding it.

Comment: On the mastering front, best practice is to list the columns you are inserting into. One SP per table for inserts/updates - although why use a SP for an insert or update? You can run the statement directly from .NET. Selects are good to have in a SP for performance tuning reasons.

Comment: Just to pile on, isn't C.R.U.D. supposed to be what ORMs are auto-magically good at?

Comment: Well, I said why I don't want (but obviously could) form select/insert/update statements inside my application, however, I consider this a bad solution. I wanted to request/send data through 4-6 procedures, which are predefined for all my 14 tables. Imagine what a pain would be creating one of each for 20 or 40 tables.

Comment: I've looked into using procedures to create logic for select/insert/update. Then why would I do so, when I can define one procedure on dbms side and call it inside an application? Also I think this a smoother solution because I lose a need for looking column names and such (sure I can use something like an entityframework and hard-copy my db, but I want to create my own api)

Comment: All I'm asking is if this kind of approach is even possible and of so, then please show me an example and/or show a guide how to accomplish my goals. Programming is not all about "you should only learn how to do certain things only one way and nothing more" you know.

Comment: Not that sure that with your approach you make it as modular as possible.

Comment: Let me rephrase what I meant by "as modular as possible". I want to achieve maximum application-db abstraction as "thin-client". Thus they only know about each-other in the moment of establishing connection, while getting\sending data. For such, all data modifications are on db side, and all user manipulations are on application side. My point of view is I can initiate insert\update procedure, push table,id,datalist (and\or other params if needed by stored procedure) to it and execute it. Also this approach can prevent possible data leaks from running application.

Answer (score 3):

This might be reasonable (to some degree) on an RDBMS that supports structured data like JSON or XML natively, but doing this the way you are planning is going to cause some real pain-in-the-rear support and, more importantly, a sql injection attack vector. I would leave this to the realm of the web backend server where it belongs.

1. You are likely going to invent your own structured data markup language and parser to solve this as sql server. That's a wheel that doesn't need to be reinvented. If you do end up building this, highly consider going with JSON to avoid all the issues that structured data inherently bring with it, assuming your version of sql server supports json parsing/packaging.
2. Your front end that packages your data into your SDML is going to have to assume column ordinals, but column ordinal is not something that one should rely on in a database. SQL Amateurs often do, I know from years in the industry and dealing with end users that are upset when a new column is introduced in a position they don't want it. Adding a column to a table shouldn't break an application. If it does, that application has bad code.
3. Regarding the sql injection attack vector, your SP code is going to get ugly. You'll need to parse out each item in @data into a variable of its own in order to properly parameterize your dynamic sql that is being built. See [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/working-with-parameters-in-the-sp_executesql-stored-procedure/) under the "working with parameters" section for what that will look like. Failure to add this to your SP code means that values passed in that @data SDML could become executable SQL instead of literals and that would be very bad. This is not easy to solve in SP language. Where it IS easy to solve though is in the backend server code. Every database library on the planet supports parameterized query building/execution natively.

   Once you have this built you will be dynamically generating an INSERT statement and dynamically generating variables or an array or some data structure to pass in parameters to the INSERT statement to avoid sql injection attacks. It's going to be dynamic, on top of dynamic, on top of dynamic which leads to:
4. From a support context, imagine that your application just totally throws up one day. You have to dive into investigate. You track the SDML that your front end created that caused the failure, and you open up your SP code to troubleshoot. Imagine what this code ends up looking like

   1. It has to determine if the table exists
   2. It has to parse the SDML to get each literal
   3. It has to read DB metadata to get the column list
   4. It has to dynamically write the insert statement, listing the columns from metadata and dynamically creating sql parameters for the VALUES() list.
   5. It has to execute sending a dynamic number of variables into the dynamically generated sql.

   My support staff would hang me out to dry if they had to deal with that, and I'm the one paying them.

All of this is solved by using a proper backend to handle communication, deeper validation, sql parameter binding, error catching and handling, and all the other things that backend servers are meant to do.

I believe that your back end web server should be VERY aware of the underlying data model. It should be the connection between your view, your data, and your model. Leave the database to the things it's good at (reading and writing data). Leave your front end to the things that it's good at (presenting a UI for the end user).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like this (may need a little extra work)

```
declare @columns varchar(max);
select @columns = string_agg(name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY column_id )
from sys.all_columns
where object_id = object_id(@dataTable);

declare @sql varchar(max) = select concat('INSERT INTO ',@dataTable,' (',@columns,') VALUES (', @data, ')')

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

But please don't. If this were a good idea, there would be tons of examples of how to do it. There aren't so it's probably not a good idea.

There are however tons of examples of using ORMs or auto-generated code in stead - because that way your code is maintainable, debugable and performant.